# How can I enable the Notification module in an in-app Chromium browser? (Uncaught ReferenceError: Notification is not defined)

Tags: javascript, webview, chromium, web-notifications

I'm working on an application that has an in-app browser based on Chromium. I need to allow a user to interact with a certain web page/server (that I don't have internal access to) through this browser. Some interactions, like  clicking on specific buttons, fail with the console message "Uncaught ReferenceError: Notification is not defined". From what I can surmise, this means the server is trying to send me a notification using the Notifications API, but my browser doesn't support it. I've confirmed that `!Notification` evaluates to `true` and `"Notification" in window` evaluates to false. I've also checked for `window.chrome.notifications`, `window.webkitNotifications`, and any other kind of notification module that I could find evidence of on the Internet. Nothing related to notifications is loaded, as far as I can tell.

On Firefox, there's [apparently](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1570588) a setting that causes Notification to never be loaded at all. I'm hoping that's what's happening here, but I can't find any evidence of such a setting in Chromium browsers, much less how to disable it.

How can I allow Chromium to recognize Notification?

Comment: If all else fails, you could try injecting some javascript (a content script? or manipulate the `window` of every page directly?) that defines a global no-op `Notification` object

Comment: I'm not sure an empty Notification object will help me -- surely the page wants to do something with the Notification object, so I would just fail a little bit later on. But it is a good idea to experiment with.